# What's the best way to do unit and performance tests against WCF in .net for different machines from a visual studio test client

Tags: c#, visual-studio, integration-testing

I need do some performance tests over a solution that uses: WCF services, serialization and a lot of stuff more (framework 4.0) deployed on several machines.

using a visual studio 2010 test project, would be possible configure any option to point at the different machines where the solution is installed?

would WCF cause any problem if I try to test agains it using a binding in particular?

Comment: What are the platforms? Are they all .Net platforms that can be run on the same machine? Are they all windows platforms Visual Studio builds can target? Are they all platforms that .Net can target with either Visual Studio or Mono?

Comment: Sorry actually I meant several machines...

Comment: What edition of Visual Studio are you using? There are ways to do exactly what you want but it depends highly on the version and edition of the version you are using.

Comment: I'm using 2010 version

Answer (score 1):

I would create a test project, add references to the WCF services you want to test, and simply start testing. If you want something for complete end to end performance testing you can look at Microsofts Performance Testing suite (You can use this to load/stress test etc...)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "Lab Management". Those features are [built in to Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936084%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on Visual Studio 2010 and newer.

Depending on how complicated of a a setup you want to do you may need a server running Hyper-V and a license for [System Center Virtual Machine Manager (SCVMM)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/system-center-2012-r2) (it is not cheep).